# How to count for a specific value column wise?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made the table with 4 columns using mysql.

Each column have datatype as `BIT`.

**I have data like this:**

```
ColA  ColB ColC Cold
1     1    1     1
1     0    0     1
0     0    1     0
```

**I wants to have query that will return the column name and no.of 1s it will have, like following:**

```
ColA ColB ColC Cold
2    1    2    2
```

I have thinked about group by, aggregate function, but not able to design the query.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please edit the title, and I will remove downvoting.

Comment: A query doesn't return column names. The person using the db (you) **knows** the column names upfront and **selects** them. Please, elaborate what you wish to achieve. Don't start off with *how* you think you should achieve it.

Comment: Actually I wants to fetch the No.of 1s each column have. Because I wants to make some summaries from that count

Comment: Why there is Down votes for my question? I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment to AK47's answer, you may prefer

```
select 
sum(colA) as colA, 
sum(colB) as colB, 
sum(colC) as colC, 
sum(colD) as cold -- I'm frozen
from Table1
```

See the diff in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d75c2d/4)

Comment: @AK47 absolutely not, but I think he may not really want what he seems to want ;)

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Sorry for my bad question design

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Select 'ColA',Sum(ColA) from myTable
Union All
Select 'ColB',Sum(ColB) from myTable
Union All
Select 'ColC',Sum(ColC) from myTable
Union All
Select 'ColD',Sum(ColD) from myTable
```

Comment: Can't I can do this in single query, if I don't want column names

Comment: No my friend,as N.B. said above in comment, SQL Query can't return column name.

Comment: You probably can make a query which does the same thing and has only one `SELECT` and `FROM` but it will be much messier than this and won't have any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Ashfaq,
  I think what you want to do is this :

```
SELECT 'ColA' AS COL, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab WHERE ColA=1) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ColB' AS COL, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab WHERE ColB=1) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ColC' AS COL, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab WHERE ColC=1) UNION ALL
SELECT 'ColD' AS COL, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tab WHERE ColD=1)
```

I hope it will helps you